# Getting error when implement jquery with selenium

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium

The following code tries to remove an item from a facebook page and append it to another id. But I get an error and I can't find the problem.

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

```
@BeforeTest
public void launchbrowser(){
    String baseUrl = "http://www.facebook.com";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("anyman@hotmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("deltaduck");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();

}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {


    remove();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    append();

}


protected void click(String elementId){
    String script ="document.getElementById('" + elementId + "').click();";

    executeJavascript(script);


}


protected void remove(){
    String remove ="$('userNavigationLabel').remove();";
    executeJavascript(remove);
}

protected void append(){
    String append ="$('privacyFlyoutLabel').append('u_0_f');";
    executeJavascript(append);
}

private void executeJavascript(String script){

    JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    je.executeScript(script);       
}
```

}
                                                                 The error message I get is:

`.org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: $(...).append is not a function
Command duration or timeout: 26 milliseconds

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: $(...).append is not a function
Command duration or timeout: 26 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.43.0', revision: 'accb3003b9fb8f7cae30f9669b4c594a065396a6', time: '2014-09-09 22:22:51'
System info: host: 'JARVIS', ip: '140.203.209.182', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: a8a7480e-8e66-499b-b660-803e10e91197
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=31.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:508)
    at Main.executeJavascript(Main.java:65)
    at Main.append(Main.java:54)
    at Main.test(Main.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: $(...).append is not a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that on a Facebook page, `$` is not jQuery. I don't know what it is but calling `$('privacyFlyoutLabel')` will return the element that has the id `privacyFlyoutLabel`. With jQuery this would return an element whose *tag name* is `privacyFlyoutLabel`. To get the element with the *id* `privacyFlyoutLabel` with jQuery, you'd have to request `$('#privacyFlyoutLabel')`.

What you get from `$` is a DOM node, not a jQuery object and thus does not have the `.append` method.

Options:

1. Forget about jQuery. Write code that accesses the DOM directly.
2. Try to load jQuery in that page before doing what you are trying to do. This would entail adding a `script` element to load jQuery and the calling `jQuery.noConflict()` to restore `$`. The problem though is that there is no guarantee that `jQuery.noConflict` would restore `$` *before* any of the asynchronous code already running on the page needs to use it. I've done a few tests with `setTimeout` and determined that an asynchronous operation launched earlier can execute between two `script` elements. So this option could actually cause failures in the code that Facebook relies on.